# Problem with deleting array which containts other arrays with specific id item in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, filter

I have Array which containts a lots of arrays which containts {id and content}.

Example : `[Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)].`

Im trying to delete Array with ID param. It deletes but state of Array.Length doesnt change because i only deleted Item of array ,not whole of one array.

What i want to do is delete () -> than result should be

`[[Array(1), Array(1)]`

What i got?  `[Array(0), Array(1), Array(1)]`

There is code what im tried to do :

```
return (
   <div>
      <h1>{tasks.length}</h1>
         {tasks.map((task) => {
            return (<div>
               {task.map((con) => {
                  return (<div>
                     <h3 className="hrandom">{con.content}
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => { deleted(con.id) }}>Delete</button></h3>
                  </div>
               )
            })}
         </div>)
      })
   }
</div>)
```

And the delete function :

```
const deleted = (id) => {
   Axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/api/delete/', { data: { id: id } }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
   });
   const b = tasks.map((tod) => tod.filter((i) => i.id !== id ));
   setTasks(b);
};
```

Comment: You're missing the `key` attribute which is **required** when rendering an array. [See docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys). **Note**: do not use the index as a key, use a unique ID of each item.

Comment: Why not just : `setTasks(tasks => tasks.filter(t => t[0].id !== id)) `?

Comment: Cesara ur answer works pretty good, but i dont understand why u use index[0]

Answer (score 0):

In your `map`, you're removing the items from the inner array but not the outer array itself. You could do this in a single line, but for simplicity and readability, add a second `filter` to the outer array:

```
const b = tasks.map((tod) => tod.filter((i) => i.id !== id )).filter(arr => arr.length > 0);
```

This will remove any inner arrays that have been emptied, in a very readable manner. However, noting the inner array always has length `1`, you could destructure cleanly like so:

```
const b = tasks.filter(([{ id: inner }]) => inner !== id);
```

The destructure syntax takes the `id` property of the object that is the first element of the inner array, and compares it to `id`.

Answer (score 0):

For your example; instead of using a `filter` inside a `map` function - which still returns an array of the same length, you should use the `filter` function to filter out the parent array directly:

```
const b = tasks.filter((tod) => tod.findIndex((i) => i.id === id ) < 0);
```

However, if there is only one array entry that will contain that `id`, filter may not be the greatest choice as it will loop across the entire `tasks` array even if the `id` has already been found. In such case, I would recommend first finding the index of the element that contains an array with the `id` and using `array.splice` to remove it from the `tasks` array as follows:

```
const index = tasks.findIndex((tod) => tod.findIndex((i) => i.id === id ) > -1);
if (index > 0) {
  tasks.splice(index, 1);
}
```